# How to properly use `flutter --no-build` (or speed up builds where only Dart code was changed)?

Tags: flutter

NOTE: I am looking for a solution WITHOUT hot restarting/reloading here!

I have a Flutter project and run it with:

`flutter run`

After 1-2 minutes of building, the app is started on my iPhone.

Then, I kill the application and change one line of Dart code. Then I restart the app with:

`flutter run --no-build`

The app is built again for 1-2 minutes and then started.

Is there a way to (re)start an application without the entire build cycle, but still update the Dart code?

Answer (score 3):

There's an option `flutter run --use-application-binary ...`. Run the most recent application binary using this option and then use Hot Reload (or Hot Restart) to update the app.

(Yes, I know: the solution uses hot restart or hot reload even though you don't want that - I still posted it because it might still help... ;-))

Comment: Note that you don't see this option with `flutter run -h`, instead use the more verbose `flutter run -h -v`.